# Filtering Database and splitting Data into tables

Tags: vba, excel

I have a database that has status update of 15 projects. The database is updated daily but not all projects has an update everyday.

What I'm planning to is to write a code that filters that database on projects basis and combine all updates for each project on a separate table.

the code below successfully combined the updates for the selected project and pasted it on another sheet but the problem is that since its a loop, every time if the if statesmen is true its copying the project name more than one time. What I want is a help on how to only copy the project name 1 time and paste it as a title for the table and then paste all related updates for that project.

Please be noted that the code will be repeated 15 times since I have 15 projects but what I have below is only for project1 so please if you also know a way how to loop this instead of repating the code 15 times, For example:( project1,project2, etc)

```
Sub report()

Sheet4.Activate

Dim project1 As String
Dim project2 As String
Dim project3 As String
Dim project4 As String
Dim project5 As String
Dim project6 As String
Dim project7 As String
Dim project8 As String
Dim project9 As String
Dim project10 As String
Dim project11 As String
Dim project12 As String
Dim project13 As String
Dim project14 As String
Dim project15 As String

Dim finalrow As Integer    
Dim i As Integer

project1 = Sheet4.Range("U1").Value
project2 = Sheet4.Range("U2").Value
project3 = Sheet4.Range("U3").Value
project4 = Sheet4.Range("U4").Value
project5 = Sheet4.Range("U5").Value
project6 = Sheet4.Range("U6").Value
project7 = Sheet4.Range("U7").Value
project8 = Sheet4.Range("U8").Value
project9 = Sheet4.Range("U9").Value
project10 = Sheet4.Range("U10").Value
project11 = Sheet4.Range("U11").Value
project12 = Sheet4.Range("U12").Value
project13 = Sheet4.Range("U13").Value
project14 = Sheet4.Range("U14").Value
project15 = Sheet4.Range("U15").Value

finalrow = Sheet4.Range("A2000").End(xlUp).Row    
i = 0

For i = 1 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 1) = project1 Then
        Sheet7.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = project1        

        If Cells(i, 1) = project1 Then
            Sheet4.Range(Sheet4.Cells(i, 2), Sheet4.Cells(i, 8)).Copy
            Sheet7.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats           
        End If
    End If    
Next i        

Sheet7.Activate                

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `project()` array, and then use a `For` loop to enter all the values inside from column "U".

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub report()

Dim project() As String
Dim finalrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long

ReDim project(1 To 15)

With Sheet4
    For i = 1 To 15
        project(i) = Sheet4.Range("U" & i).Value
    Next i

    finalrow = .Range("A2000").End(xlUp).Row    

    '===== I think this is what you meant =====        
    ' Option 1: looping through each row and check it againt all elements inside project array    
    For i = 1 To finalrow
        For j = 1 To UBound(project)
            If .Cells(i, 1) = project(j) Then
                Sheet7.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = project(j)

                .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 8)).Copy
                Sheet7.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
             End If                
        Next j
    Next i


    '===== Option 2: use the Match function to see if the value in Cells(i, 1) equals one of the =====
    ' elements inside project array
    For i = 1 To finalrow
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(i, 1), project, 0)) Then ' <-- successful match
            j = Application.Match(.Cells(i, 1), project, 0) ' <-- get the element index inside the project array
            Sheet7.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = project(j)

            .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 8)).Copy
            Sheet7.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        End If
    Next i
End With    

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your effort ;).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your effort ;). regarding your code is exactly doing the  same as my code but with two problems. First, the project name is duplicated a lot and its not organized. for example (cell A1 shows Project1 "title", A2 shows Project1 update A3 shows Project 5 "title" A4 shows project5 update, A5 shows project1 "title" again!! A6 shows project1 second update. what I want is a table, like (A1 is project1 title and beneath it all project1 updates with repeating the title. Many thanks

Comment: you should share a snapshot of your data structure, and what is the desired result - it will help to understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: This is the database: [![image.jpg](https://s29.postimg.org/akamca9qv/image.jpg)](https://postimg.org/image/w6pmtb8b7/) and this is how I want it [![image.jpg](https://s29.postimg.org/fmtlqu8nb/image.jpg)](https://postimg.org/image/d5hujkoqr/). As you can see what I want is to group each project on separate table or at least to separate them by a header.

Answer (score 0):

'For avoiding repetition of project names, you run another macro. Pseudo code is given below:

```
Sub HideRepeatedNames()
'presuming project names are in column1
for n=1 to lastrow
thisrow=cells(n,1)
nextrow=cells(n+1,1)
if thisrow=nextrow then
nextrow=cells(n+1,1).interior.color=cells(n+1,1).font.color
end if
End Sub
```